# Jquery slideDown child ul

Tags: jquery

How can I slide down ONLY the child ul of the element that is being hovered over?

```
<ul>
        <li class="main">
            <a href="real_estate.htm">Real Estate </a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li> <a href="#">Consulting Services</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">Investment</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">Property Management</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">Development</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main">
            <a href="investment.htm">Investment</a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="#">Philosophy</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Criteria</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
</ul>

Jquery 

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sub").hide();
    $(".main").hover(function() {
        $(".sub").slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add context:

```
$(".sub", this).slideDown('slow');
```

The second parameter of the selector is a context. By passing `this`, we're telling the selector to *only* match the `.sub` elements that are found within `this`, where `this`, represents the `.main` that you are currently hovering.

The equivalent would be:

```
$(this).find('.sub').slideDown('slow');
```

More at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context

Comment: Thank you! Thank worked! How can I also, slideUp the previously hovered ul when I move the mouse over the next li?

Comment: `$.hover()` takes two anonymous functions. Currently, you are only using the first space. You could use the second to hide the nested `ul`. See: http://api.jquery.com/hover/ So it would be along the lines of `$(el).hover(function(){/*show*/},function(){/*hide*/});`

Comment: How can I keep the subcategories open when I'm on the main category's page?

Comment: @MG1 There are several methods you could use. The easiest would be to add a class to the main category and then do something like this `.main.opened .sub { display:block }`. That way, the sub categories will be visible when the main category has the class 'opened'.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would get that working if I have the entire menu on one php page that's being included in all the other pages?  How will it know which sub category to display?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".main").hover(function() {
    $(".sub", this).slideDown('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sub").hide();
    $(".main").hover(function() {
        $(this).find(".sub").slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```

`this` refers to the hovered `.main` and `.find` will find all `.sub` elements within it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question. In this case you may use more selectors or find, first, last functions of jQuery.

CSS:

```
.sub { display: none; /* probably you will need height: 0; and/or position relative; left: Xpx; top: Ypx; to make the sub-menus at good position for showing.. */ }
```

JavaScript:

```
function hideMenu(obj)
{
    // This is valid. Depending on situation you will see below another sample.
    $(obj).find("ul").slideUp();
    // or
    // $(obj + " ul").slideUp();
}

function showMenu(obj)
{
    // This is valid. Depending on situation you will see below another sample.
    $(obj).find("ul").slideDown();
    // or
    // $(obj + " ul").slideDown();
}
```

I suppose you are generating the whole page... In this case you will have to generate li elements in the same way, but add onmouseover="showMenu(this)" onmouseout="hideMenu(this)":

```
<li onmouseover="showMenu(this)" onmouseout="hideMenu(this)">...</li>
```

You have to include the JavaScript file in your html - in the head tag with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path to the file"></script>
```

This is a schematic representation.