# How edit this script to display only one submenu

Tags: jquery

I used this code to display submenu on hover. I tried to use delay parameter, but I need to show submenu only if hover takes 1s.

```
$('.mainmenu li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.submenu').fadeIn( 'slow' );
},
function() {
  $(this).find('.submenu').slideUp( 1 ).delay( 3000 );
```

I found this code, and its exactly what I need, but I have only one problem, this script show all submenus.

```
$(function() {
var timeoutId;
$(".mainmenu li").hover(function() {
    if (!timeoutId) {
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
            timeoutId = null;
            $(".submenu").slideDown('slow');
       }, 1500);
    }
},
function () {
    if (timeoutId) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = null;
    }
    else {
       $(".submenu").slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

});

I tried to put this line:

```
$(this).find('.submenu').fadeIn( 'slow' );
```

but it won't work.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: can you post your HTML?

Comment: just save your `this` to `that`, like `hover(function() { var that = $(this); ...  that.find(".submenu").slideDown('slow');...}`

Comment: Can I suggest [this plugin](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not post your HTML, assuming there exists one `.submenu` for each `.mainmenu li`

Try this: this will show only the `.submenu` of the current `li`, and not all `.submenu`

New Code change required:

```
$(this).find('.submenu').slideDown('slow');
```

Full Code:

```
$(function() {
var timeoutId;
$(".mainmenu li").hover(function() {
    if (!timeoutId) {
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
            timeoutId = null;
            $(this).find('.submenu').slideDown('slow');//made changes to this line
       }, 1500);
    }
},
function () {
    if (timeoutId) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = null;
    }
    else {
       $(".submenu").slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank You. Unfortunately it won't work. [Here is my project](http://ventostudio.eu/gosc/cosmedic/)

Comment: In every .mainmenu li there is more than 1 submenus.

Comment: what do you mean by there is more than 1 submenus. I just opened your project and inspected in chrome, I see mainmenu li and under each li there is only one <ul class="submenu">. I meant there is only one `.submenu` not actual menu items.

Comment: You're right, my fall. Have You got any other idea, how fix this code?

Comment: The change I mentioned above in my answer should work....as an alternative, try this: $(".submenu", this).slideDown('slow');

I found the following on stackoverflow which is what I think you are looking for, the answer for this is the same as the one I suggested, not sure why it isnt working for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656202/jquery-slidedown-child-ul